# загрузка данных в БД через форму при помощи insert

Tags: php, mysql, form

Есть таблица в которой есть поля: *ID* (автоинкремент), *Short_Name* (`varchar`), *Full_Name* (`varchar`), *Comment* (`varchar`), *Date_Entered* (по умолчанию добавляется текущее время и дата, `timestamp`).

Есть форма, в которой есть поля для ввода информации для добавления в таблицу. Поле для ввода *Short_Name* (`text`), *Full_Name* (`text`), *Comment* (`textarea`).

Код php страницы для добавления:

```
<? include
('db_connect.php');
$short_name =  $_POST['Short_Name'];
$full_name = $_POST['Full_Name'];
$comment =  $_POST['Comment']; 

$sqlinsertsa="INSERT INTO  DimLabAnalysisType (`ID`, `Short_Name`,`Full_Name`, 
`Comment`, `Date_Entered`)
VALUES (NULL, '$short_name','$full_name','$comment', NULL);";
$result = mysqli_query($query); 
?>
```

Данные в базу в данном случае не добавляются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Зачем вы автоинкременту `NULL` назначаете? Ну и опять классика с SQL-инъекциями.

Comment: @andreymal, действительно незачем, но это и не ошибка. так тоже будет работать

Comment: Точка-с-запятой в тексте запроса лишняя *NULL);*, но это опять не причина ошибки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Запрос выглядит нормально. Ошибка в PHP: y [**mysqli_query()**](http://php.net/mysqli_query) первым обязательным параметром должен быть link, вторым текст запроса. А у вас всего один параметр и там неизвестная переменная. Из чужих кусочков текст собирали?

Узнать о таких проколах можно включив вывод всех предупреждений. Почитайте про [**отладку**](http://phpfaq.ru/debug).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$short_name =  $_POST['Short_Name'];
$full_name = $_POST['Full_Name'];
$comment =  $_POST['Comment']; 
$short_name =  mysql_real_escape_string($short_name); // экранирование
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($full_name); // экранирование
$comment =  mysql_real_escape_string($comment); // экранирование


$sql = "INSERT INTO DimLabAnalysisType (`Short_Name`,`Full_Name`, 
`Comment`, `Date_Entered`)
VALUES ('$short_name','$full_name','$comment', NULL)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```